# How can I use AppleScript to check if PowerPoint is playing a presentation?

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I'm trying to write some AppleScript that checks if PowerPoint 2011 is currently playing a presentation.

Previously, I wrote the following code for Keynote.

```
on isKeynotePlaying()
    tell application "Keynote"
        get properties
        return (not frozen) and playing
    end tell
end isKeynotePlaying
```

After searching through PowerPoint's AppleScript library, properties and attributes of classes, and Google search results, I still haven't been able to generate an equivalent solution.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After delving even deeper into PowerPoint's AppleScript library, I stumbled upon the `slide show view` class. Here's my solution.

```
on isPowerPointPlaying()
    tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        return slide state of slide show view of slide show window of active presentation is slide show state running
    end tell
end isPowerPointPlaying
```